# Why does a class' body get executed at definition time?

Tags: python, class, python-internals

In contrast to functions, a class' body is executed at definition time:

```
class A(object):
    print 'hello'
```

Out:

```
hello
```

Why is it the case? Is it related to `@classmethod` / `@staticmethod` methods and class attributes?

Comment: When else would it get executed?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I could understand their confusion. It would be intuitive that a class body would only get executed upon instantiation of the first instance of the class (although that is not the case).

Comment: a simple answer - because that is the way the language is defined..

Comment: Ask yourself: how could you use the class if it *wasn't* executed when the module is loaded?

Comment: Unlike in some languages, a class is a first-class object (no pun intended) that exists in memory, rather than a static instruction to the compiler on how to create objects later. A class object is created by executing the `class` statement, which is simply a declarative wrapper around a call to the `type` function (or whatever callable is specified as the metaclass, but you don't need to worry about that technicality).

Comment: Also consider that _some_ parts of a function are executed at definition time: specifically, its default arguments are evaluated. And that also applies to any functions that are defined inside the function.

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, to be precise, the `def` statement is executed. Part of that execution is to evaluate the default arguments.

Comment: @chepner Nicely put. Defining the function name is the main thing, evaluating default arguments is a just a side "benefit". :) And I guess the function's local name space is also set up at that time?

Comment: @JohnzWinck For example lazily when needed. Don't misunderstand me - I like it that way more too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Everything** is executed at the module level when Python first imports a module. Function bodies (and generator expression bodies) are the *exception* here, not the rule. Python executes everything to create the *objects* contained in a module; like everything in Python, classes are objects, and so are functions.

The only reason a class body uses a separate code object is because a class body is executed in a separate namespace, with that namespace then forming the class attributes. Class bodies are not the only such namespaces; set and dict comprehensions, and in Python 3, list comprehensions are also executed with a separate namespace, scoping their locals.

So functions and generator expressions are the exception, expressly because their whole *purpose* is to be executed at a later time. Note that the function *definition* **is** executed:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('def foo(): pass', '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object foo at 0x106aef2b0, file "<stdin>", line 1>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (foo)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `MAKE_FUNCTION` bytecode there creates the function object, together with the stored bytecode for that function, and the result is bound to the global name `foo`.

Class objects are no different here; the `class` statement produces a class object, and as part of that object, we need to know the attributes from the class body.

If Python did *not* execute the class body, other code could not make any use of those class members. You couldn't access class attributes (including class methods and static methods), you couldn't *set* class attributes, etc.

Any functions that are part of the class body are of course *not* executed at that time. Just like top-level functions, only a `MAKE_FUNCTION` bytecode is executed and the resulting local name (set with `STORE_FAST`) is then turned into a class attribute, analogous to a global function object being bound to a global with `STORE_NAME`.

Answer (score 11):

According to [Class definitions - Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> **A class definition is an executable statement.** It first evaluates the
>   inheritance list, if present. Each item in the inheritance list should
>   evaluate to a class object or class type which allows subclassing. **The
>   class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see section
>   Naming and binding), using a newly created local namespace and the
>   original global namespace.** (Usually, the suite contains only function
>   definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, its execution
>   frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved. A class
>   object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes
>   and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary. The class
>   name is bound to this class object in the original local namespace.

Comment: Side note: This innocently looking part: *A class object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary* is a source of a lot of confusion when it comes to name resolution in class's methods...

Comment: This just states that the class body is indeed executed. It doesn't really motivate *why* it is executed. It is a 'because' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two classes `A` and `B`:

```
class A:
    p=4

def add(i, j):
    return i + j

class B:
    p = add(2, 2)

a = A()
b = B()
print("a.p:",a.p)
print("b.p:",b.p)
```

Both have similar function and in both `p` is equal to 4. This occurs in definition and not instantiation.

In definition of class B the value of p is calculated and is used later during instantiation. This means everything about these properties is created beforehand.