# Instantiation of "type" in Python

Tags: python

When are objects of type `type` instantiated in Python?

I understand that Python classes are objects themselves (being instances of class `type`). When are these objects instantiated?

I guess it's either on module import or on the first instantiation of the class, but I could not find any documentation on this topic. I'm especially interested in answers for Python 2.7, but would like to be pointed to (possible) differences in Python 3 as well.

Comment: Classes are created whenever Python executes them (i.e. where you wrote `class`), like any other object.

Comment: All new-style classes are of type `type`, and they are created when a `class` statement is executed or you explicitly use the `type()` callable to create a class. Is that what you are looking for? Your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Related: [Why does a class' body get executed at definition time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26193653)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are instantiated as soon as the end of the class scope is reached.

```
class foo(object):
  pass

bar = foo # Works

print type(foo)

class foo2(object):
  bar = foo2 # NameError
```