# Prevent Python from loading certain parts of a script when it gets loaded

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

**Background**: I'm trying to reduce the time it takes for my tests to complete running.

I learned recently that when the Python interpreter loads a file, it executes all the code it finds therein. (Ref: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/%22Link%20here.%22))

Is there a way to prevent certain parts of the file from being executed by the interpreter ? Reason is, I have a script that creates a session and assigns that to a class attribute. The script looks something like this.

```
 def login():
     // Gets auth session from an api. This takes some seconds.
     return // session

 class Something(object):
     class_session = login()
```

Now I tried to mock this login process but then, when I run my unit tests (I'm using nose btw), I think Python reads, immediately executes this script and then tries to create a session before it gets to mock the method. This takes a couple of seconds and my tests subsequently take longer to complete running (Please correct me if this is not the flow).

- Is there a way I can prevent Python from executing the script when it reads it (without wrapping the code in a function)?
- If so, what is the most Pythonic way to handle this?
- Also, how long should a well written test take to run by default. I think this should be less than **1** second (Not sure where I got that impression from tho).

Please share some insights, thanks.

Comment: what about from bla import foo ?

Comment: @Alex That still would load the whole script.

Comment: If `class_session` is a class attribute then you can initialize it as `None` and move `Something.class_session = login()` to a method (even `__init__`) to keep it from being called when the object is first hit.

Comment: Rather than having global data, pass it around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your code in such a manner that it does not do too much upon simply declaring things. Only when you explicitly call a function or instantiate a class should your code do "actual work".

```
class Something(object):
    class_session = login()
```

This creates a class property `class_session`, which obviously must happen at the time the class gets defined, else it wouldn't be a class property. This necessitates the execution of `login()` at this time.

To do this properly only when a new object is instantiated, move this code into the constructor and make it an instance property:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.class_session = login()
```

Whether it makes more sense to have something be a class property or an instance property is impossible to say without knowing what this code is supposed to do. However, you really should delay all "real work" until a function is explicitly called; triggering a login upon importing the module is madness.

Answer (score 1):

To keep `login()` from being hit when the file is imported it will need to be moved out of the class attribute space.  You can do this by placing it in a method like below:

```
def login():
    // Gets auth session from an api. This takes some seconds.
    return // session

class Something(object):
    class_session = None

    def __init__(self):
        if Something.class_session is None:   # or self.__class__.class_session
            Something.class_session = login()
```

`Something.class_session = login()` needs to be within a function or method to prevent it from being run on import.  The way it is written above, `login()` will be executed the first time a `Something()` is created.

See [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193653/why-does-a-class-body-get-executed-at-definition-time) for a little more about what is run when the module is imported.