# Need help understanding why my code doesn't run [python]

Tags: python-3.x

So my goal is to make an ordering system for a cafe with various types of coffee available. Right now I'm having trouble understanding why my code doesn't run, whenever I execute the code nothing happens and I'm not sure why

```
class Coffee(object):

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def coffee (self, coffee_type, price):
        self.coffee_type = coffee_type
        self.price = price

class Order(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def newOrder (self, coffee_type, coffee_amount):
        this.coffee_type = coffee_type
        this.coffee_amount = coffee_amount




class Main(object):

    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name


    from Coffee import coffee

    flat_white = coffee("1 : Flat White", 3.50)
    long_black = coffee("2 : Long Black", 3.50)
    cappuccino = coffee("3 : Cappuccino", 4.00)
    espresso = coffee("4 : Espresso", 3.25)
    latte = coffee("5 : Latte", 3.50)

    Ordering = 'Y'

    while Ordering == 'Y':
        try:
            order_coffee = int(input("What coffee would you like to order?", pprint (vars(coffee))))
            break

        except:
            ValueError
            print ("wrong input")

        order_amount = input("How many would you like to order?")

        if order_coffee == 1:
            new_Order(flat_white, order_amount)

        elif order_coffee == 2:
            new_Order(long_black, order_amount)

        elif order_coffee == 3:
            new_Order(cappuccino, order_amount)

        elif order_coffee == 4:
            new_Order(espresso, order_amount)

        elif order_coffee == 5:
            new_Order(latte, order_amount)

        else:
            print ("Please enter a valid number")
            break
```

Comment: This code will not execute anything as is. How are you trying to run your ordering system? You do not need a main object, you can just have that code in a `if __name__=="__main__":` block. Or put the code in a `main()` function called within that block.

Comment: When I run your code the line `from Coffee import coffee` raises `ImportError: No module named 'Coffee'` please explain how you are trying to run your program or there is no way anyone will be able to help.

Comment: As @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen pointed out, my comment here is wrong. It will run. You can see my answer below for a couple issues and solutions that I saw.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are several issues with your code. I will try to help you out with a couple.

First, no need for the `__init__` method to accept a name. Just make the method accept the necessary information for the object:

```
class Coffee(object):
    def __init__ (self, coffee_type, price):
        self.coffee_type = coffee_type
        self.price = price

class Order(object):
    def __init__(self, coffee_type, coffee_amount):
        self.coffee_type = coffee_type
        self.coffee_amount = coffee_amount
```

Second, since it does not really do anything, you can replace the `Main` class to an execution in a conditional as is typically seen in Python programs/scripts:

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    ... # put main code here
```

Next, the `except` as it is written will catch all exceptions making debugging more difficult. If you only want to catch the `ValueError`, do:

```
    except ValueError:
        print ("wrong input")
```

If you use the current flow (i.e. with the `try` `except` block, you should put all of the order logic within the `try` block as it does not make any sense outside. Also, the necessary variables needed (`order_coffee`) will not be defined if you have a `ValueError`.

Adding a `break` after accepting the order input will cause you to break out of the ordering loop after an order is entered. This is probably not intended behavior. No `break` is needed here. Ditto for after outputting `"Please enter a valid number"`.

When creating an `Order`, you just need to call `Order(coffee_type, coffee_amount)`. When you create this order, make sure to set it to a variable too. probably something like:

```
new_order = Order(flat_white, order_amount)
```

Printing "Please enter a valid number" and "wrong input" is slightly redundant. You only need one of them to print under invalid input.

Lastly, `pprint` will print stuff out then return `None` so `print(..., pprint(x))` will print an extra `None` once it has finished pretty printing `x`, instead just call `pprint` as if it was another call to `print`.

**-- --**

Making all of these changes, you will end up with something like:

```
class Coffee(object):

    def __init__ (self, coffee_type, price):
        self.coffee_type = coffee_type
        self.price = price

class Order(object):

    def __init__(self, coffee_type, coffee_amount):
        self.coffee_type = coffee_type
        self.coffee_amount = coffee_amount

if __name__ =="__main__":

    coffee_available=[Coffee("1 : Flat White", 3.50), 
                      Coffee("2 : Long Black", 3.50), 
                      Coffee("3 : Cappuccino", 4.00), 
                      Coffee("4 : Espresso", 3.25), 
                      Coffee("5 : Latte", 3.50)]

    ordering = 'Y'

    while ordering == 'Y':

        print("Coffee Type\t\tPrice")
        print("-----------\t\t-----")
        for coffee in coffee_available:
            print("{}\t- - -\t$ {}".format(coffee.coffee_type,coffee.price))
        print()
        order_coffee = int(input("What is the number of the coffee you want? "))

        order_amount = input("How many would you like to order? ")

        new_order = None

        if order_coffee >= 1 and order_coffee <=5:
            new_order = Order(coffee_available[order_coffee-1], order_amount)

        else:
            print ("Please enter a valid number")
```

Comment: "you will not actually be running anything if you execute this file."  Did you try? The code in a class block executes like an `if True:` block (with special handling of the variables defined there) so the code in the `class Main` **will** in fact be executed. (don't get me wrong a lot of your pointers will be helpful to the OP)

Comment: I did not try to run it, I had never seen that usage before and so it was the first issue I saw. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: no problem ([related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193653/why-does-a-class-body-get-executed-at-definition-time)) The OP definitely isn't using this mechanic in the intended way.  One example use is [subprocess conditionally defining internal methods differently for windows then unix](https://github.com/tadhgmister/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1126)

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm relatively new to python and I'm just learning things about classes and functions for it. I applied the fixes you mentioned and it does work fine except I cannot seem to print the list of coffee instances and their attributes. I will continue to work on this program as i still have to implement a receipt system and to keep count on what items and how many were ordered during a day

Comment: @killerstick1 Not a problem, welcome to SO. I am sure that you can probably get it to work with `pprint`, but I would probably just create a function to print the menu since I have never used `pprint`. Another thing that you want to consider is to make sure you can exit out of the loop (i.e. check the input for some exit command and set `ordering` to something else). I have put a version of the fully edited code in the answer above.

Comment: @anon01 thank you, I will try to update my progress on this task if I incur any more problems. I was thinking of putting an exit command after I have gathered all the inputs from the user. Currently im trying to implement a receipt function which should provide a segway to other elements of my task