# Order of execution with python class

Tags: python, class, interpreter, order-of-execution

I was writing a small python script to understand a concept and got another confusion. Here's the code -

```
x = 5
y = 3

class Exp(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        print("In",x, y, self.x, self.y)
    print("Middle",x,y)

print("Out",x,y)

Exp(1,2)
```

The output is -

```
Middle 5 3
Out 5 3
In 1 2 1 2
```

Now, my concept was python interpreter starts reading and executing the code from the first line to last line. It executes the code **inside a class** only when it is "called", not when it is defined. So, the output should print "Out" first. But here it is printing "Middle" first. This should not happen, as python interpreter when first encounters "Middle" - it is within the definition, and thus should not be executed at that time. It should be executed only after reading the last line of code where the class "Exp" is called.

I searched on Google and StackOverflow for the solution but couldn't find one explaining it for the class.

Kindly help me understand where I'm getting it wrong...

Comment: No, class 'definitions' are 'executed' as they are encountered. I think you are thinking of functions and methods.

Comment: Check my answer below for a `possible` correct way of defining.

Comment: Got it... @quamrana . Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a class' body get executed at definition time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193653/why-does-a-class-body-get-executed-at-definition-time)

Answer (score 3):

Your doubt is right. I had the same doubt like 6 months back and a friend of mine helped me figure the answer out.

```py
print("Middle",x,y)
```

The above statement does not belong to any method. It belongs to the class `Exp`. The `__init__()` method is executed when an object is created and is internally called by the Python interpreter when an object is instantiated from your end. Since the above statement is not a part of any method, the interpreter executes it before invoking the `__init__` method. Since variables `x` and `y` are both available in the scope of class `Exp`, it isn't considered an error and the interpreter executes it.

If you remove the declarations of variables `x` and `y`, you will see a `NameError` like below.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("Middle",x,y)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

And this is because `x` and `y` are not even created from the class `Exp`'s perspective.

Answer (score 2):

This odd behaviour happens because your `print("Middle",x,y)` is not inside a definition of a function, so it gets called before `print("Out",x,y)`.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
x = 5
y = 3

class Exp(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        print("In",x, y, self.x, self.y)

print("Middle",x,y)
print("Out",x,y) 
Exp(1,2)
```

Whose output will be:

```
Middle 5 3
Out 5 3
In 1 2 1 2
```

One of the possible ways to correct this is to define `print("Middle",x,y)`, say within the constructor.

```
x = 5
y = 3

class Exp(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        print("In",x, y, self.x, self.y)
        print("Middle",x,y)

print("Out",x,y) 
Exp(1,2)
```

The output you will then get is:

```
Out 5 3
In 1 2 1 2
Middle 1 2
```

Comment: How do you know that this is the correct behaviour?

Comment: Reworded my answer to avoid confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Class methods are not executed as compiled, they have to be invoked.

With your code above the print(middle) statement is not defined within a class method. Whereas the print(In) statement is defined within the **init** (also called constructor) method.

When you run the code and the compiler runs through the script, the print(In) statement is not invoked until the **init**() method is called.

However this print(middle) line is not defined as a method of the Exp class, but is executable as a built-in function, despite the whitespace. Consequently as Python compiles the class Exp the print(middle) statement is invoked. This is the only time the print(middle) statement would be invoked. As it is not in a class method it cannot be accessed later in the program.

If you try the code below, you get the output 'Out' and 'In'. You would only get 'Middle' by calling Exp.test()

```
x = 5
y = 3

class Exp(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        print("In",x, y, self.x, self.y)

    def test(self):
        print("Middle",x,y)  

print("Out",x,y)

Exp(1,2)
```

Comment: How do you know that this is the 'problem'?

Comment: @quamrana is it not the 'problem'?

Comment: The code that the OP has is perfectly valid python. So the 'problem', or 'issue' is simply the OP being surprised about the outcome. You have presented code which is also perfectly valid python, but it does something else. I think the OP *wanted* `Middle` to be printed at some point during execution. With your code you would have to add something else in order to call `test()`.

Comment: @quamrana Yes you are correct. I have edited my answer accordingly.