# Why is expression/statement/variable executed before object init?

Tags: python, oop

Consider following code

```
class A():
    print("hello")
    value = 44
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Output:

```
>>> 
hello
>>>
```

The variable or expression... are inside class but outside any methods. By running this script I would expect that nothing happens because I didn't instantiate anything. Why is the interpreter executing it?

Comment: Note that `if __name__ == "__main__": pass` does nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of execution with python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55793567/order-of-execution-with-python-class)

Comment: or [Why does a class' body get executed at definition time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26193653/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code inside a `class` statement is executed immediately, as part of executing the `class` statement. Your code is roughly equivalent to

```
# Execute the body of the class statement
print("hello")
value = 44
def __init__(self):
    print("init")

# Call type, passing names defined in the body as a dict
# as the third argument
A = type("A", (), {'value': value, '__init__': __init__})

# Clean up the names, as they are not left in the global namespace
del value, __init__
```

Once the class `A` is defined, the only code that gets executed upon instantiation is the body of `_init`: `a = A()` is roughly equivalent to

```
a = A.__new__(A)
a.__init__()
```

Comment: Thank you now I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax):

> Class definitions, like function definitions (def statements) must be executed before they have any effect. (You could conceivably place a class definition in a branch of an if statement, or inside a function.)
>
> ...
>
> In practice, the statements inside a class definition will usually be function definitions, but other statements are allowed, and sometimes useful