# Why are statements in a Class executed without instantiation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I would like to understand below behavior of class in python:

```
class A:
   print("I am in class")
```

After running this code, without creating any instances I can see that print statement is executed. Without creating an instance, why is this statement executed?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because Python executes all the code in the class body.

If you want `print("I am in class")` to run only when you create an instance, try defining your class this way and see how the behaviour changes:

```
class A:
     def __init__(self):
         print("I am in class A")
```

Just to add on, I believe the answers to this previous question can give you more details: [Why does a class' body get executed at definition time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26193653/13602750)